# Redux todo example- how to remove visibility filter?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using todos-with-undo example to write my application but I can't find the way to delete the visibility functionality from this example. Here is the link to the example https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/todos-with-undo:

the main problem is in App.js file:

```
<TodoList todos={visibleTodos} onTodoClick={id => dispatch(completeTodo(id))} />
```

I am trying to replace visibleTodos with this.props.todos but it doesn't work this way. How to get rid of this visibleTodos property?

Answer (score 0):

The todos are not defined as props yet, they are on the state only. This is why you can't access them via this.props.todos

Look at this [line of code](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/todos-with-undo/containers/App.js#L58), it maps the state to props:

```
function select(state) {
   return {
      ...
      visibleTodos: selectTodos(state.todos.present, state.visibilityFilter),
      ...
   }
}
```

Here you can see, that visibleTodos are only a filtered subset. If you want to access all todos within your render method, you can do two things:

Remove the call to the method that filters the todos (selectTodos):

```
function select(state) {
   return {
      ...
      visibleTodos: state.todos.present,
      ...
   }
}
```

Or define your own new prop, accessible then via this.props.todos

```
App.propTypes = {
  ...
  todos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired

}

function select(state) {
   return {
      ...
      todos: state.todos.present
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and explanation!